# Applying formatting border change across all worksheets but one not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code to apply a purple top/bottom border to the last row of every sheet except the one titled "BudgetByMonth" however when I run it it only applies to the sheet I'm currently on. I've been staring at it for ages, can someone help me out?

```
    Sub FormatLastRow()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws.Name <> "BudgetByMonth" Then
With ws
  LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & LastRow, "BB" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
    Range("A" & LastRow, "BB" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 29
    Range("A" & LastRow, "BB" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
    Range("A" & LastRow, "BB" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 29
End With
End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `Range` objects are not using the `With` - put a period before them like this: `.Range("A" &`

Even better, you can simplify it like this:

```
LastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
With ws.Range("A" & LastRow, "BB" & LastRow)
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
    .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 29
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
    .Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 29
End With
```

That way, if the `"A"` or `"BB"` changes later, you only need to change it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

When using a with statement, you need to put a period before the object you are referring to.  In your current code you are only referring to the activesheet because you are missing the periods.

```
Sub FormatLastRow()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "BudgetByMonth" Then
            With ws
                LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("A" & LastRow, "BB" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
                .Range("A" & LastRow, "BB" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).ColorIndex = 29
                .Range("A" & LastRow, "BB" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = xlMedium
                .Range("A" & LastRow, "BB" & LastRow).Borders(xlEdgeTop).ColorIndex = 29
            End With
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```